# How to avoid errors in saving data - Cakephp

Tags: validation, cakephp

I'm using Cakephp and trying to put in a method to make sure our reservation system doesn't let two users book the same appointment.  Ex. User 1 opens the appointment, and User 2 opens it simultaneously.  User 1 books the appointment.  User 2 tries to book it but the system checks and sees it is no longer available.

I imagine this would take place in validation, or in a beforeSave(), but can't figure out how to do it.

Right now I made a function in the model to call from the controller.  In the controller I have:

```
if ($this->Timeslot->checkIfNotAvailable()) {
$this->Session->setFlash('This timeslot is no longer available');
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'partner_homepage')); 
}
```

and in the model I have this function:

```
function checkIfNotAvailable($data) {
    $this->recursive = -1;
    $timeslot = $this->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Timeslot.id' => $this->data['Timeslot']['id'])
        )
    );
    if ($timeslot['student_id'] == 0) {
        //They can reserve it, do not spring a flag
        return false;
    } else {
        //Throw a flag!
        return true;
    }
}
```

I think I'm mixed up using custom validation when it's not called for.  And it's not working obviously.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you have is working, you can stick with it, you could also try creating a beforeValidate() call back function in your Model.

```
class YourModel extends AppModel {
   function beforeValidate(){
      if( !$this->checkIfNotAvailable( $this->data ) ) {
         unset($this->data['YourModel']['time_slot']);
      }
      return true; //this is required, otherwise validation will always fail
   }
}
```

This way you remove the time_slot before it goes to validation and it will drop a validation error at that point, kicking the user back to the edit page and getting them to pick a different time slot, ideally the updated data entry page will no longer have the used time slot available.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the suggestion.  My way isn't working right now...do you see any errors in what I'm doing with that method?

Comment: Your attempt is probably failing because you're using a `find('all')` which will return an entire array of records, this making it impossible to test `$timeslot['student_id']`.

Try switching it to a `find('first')` and you might be OK.

Comment: OK...thanks steve, got it to work both ways.  The find('all') was one problem, and also I needed to send $this->data when I called "checkIfNotAvailable".  Thanks for your help!